# xUbuntu on Lenovo T450s

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, xfce, lenovo

I was trying to install xUbuntu Desktop 14.4 on Lenovo T450s without success. The standard installation freezes immediately after showing the two icons in the beginning never switching to graphics mode.

Did anyone manage to install it from stock installation.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install basic Ubuntu system using the Ubuntu Server edition (http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server).

When asked about packages that should be installed, I left all the check-boxes empty, which leaves mostly barebone Ubuntu, which boots to console.

Then following this guide: http://www.linux.com/community/blogs/133-general-linux/803937-installupgrade-linux-kernel-to-3183-stable-in-ubuntulinux-mintpeppermint , Updated the kernel version to 3.18-3.

After that to get xfce4, I used:

`sudo apt-get install xfce4-desktop`

The display driver still has issues though. Portions of the screen are not repainted and sometimes even the terminal stops responding but it's a start.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Your answer would be improved by providing detail that someone without experience could follow. How did you install the Ubuntu Server edition with minimal packages, How did you upgrade the kernel to 3.18-3 and how did you install xfce4?  Of course if the system is highly unstable perhaps this should be an [edit] to your question instead of an answer. :-)